# Using an enum as a named parameter in Spring Query annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, enums, named-parameters

I have a query in a spring JpaRepository that looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(c) FROM #{#entityName} c "
        + "WHERE c.feature = 'BBN'  OR c.feature = :feature "
        + "AND c.rating <= :rating "
        + "AND c.article.ean = c.identification.article.ean "
        + "AND c.date BETWEEN :from AND :to "
        + "AND c.identification.type IN (:types)") 
Long countAlgorithmMatchesWithRatingAndTypeBetweenDates(
        @Param("rating") Integer rating, 
        @Param("from") Date from, 
        @Param("to") Date to, 
        @Param("feature") FeatureType feature, 
        @Param("types") IdentificationType... types);
```

I have enabled trace debugging for hibernate, and I can see that the parameters that are enums are not bound:

```
Hibernate: select count(classifier0_.uuid) as col_0_0_ from matchx.classifier classifier0_ cross join matchx.identification identifica1_ where classifier0_.identification_uuid=identifica1_.uuid and (classifier0_.feature='BBN' or classifier0_.feature=? and classifier0_.rating<=? and classifier0_.article_ean=identifica1_.article_ean and (classifier0_.date between ? and ?) and (identifica1_.type in (?)))
2018-04-05 07:46:43.373 TRACE 11427 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [3]
2018-04-05 07:46:43.374 TRACE 11427 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2017]
2018-04-05 07:46:43.374 TRACE 11427 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2019]
```

The entities responsible for these enums have their fields annotated like this:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private FeatureType feature;
```

Everything looks good in the database, but Hibernates queries seem to be acting up for reasons I can't see.

Should I pass the enum types as strings instead? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: your query looks incorrect; you have duplicated condition in 'where' (1)"WHERE c.feature = 'BBN' " and (2)"AND c.feature = :feature"

Comment: @Kh.Taheri you are right, I tried using the above modified query but it still doesn't map the enum types.

Comment: the debugging output still incorrect! can you update it!!

Comment: @Kh.Taheri sorry, I was on my phone. It's updated now

Comment: I have the same issue with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, @hochas did you finally find an asnwer

Comment: @storm_buster I am using the same query as above. Try creating a table with only a column for your enum type and you will see that it gets inserted.

Answer (score 1):

I created a query using only a single parameter that was an enum. Doing that I could verify that the value was indeed sent, but it is not visible in the output.

Do not trust the `binding parameter` message blindly :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to consider this:

Enums are basically Macros to ints.
They are numbers that you gave a name to so you can call them easily in your code and make it readable.

When you want to save an enum, save it's value using `myEnum.getValue()` that returns the int equivalent of the enum you call it on, then save it as an int in your DB.

edit: well, grammar...

Comment: I'm converting a legacy database that has too many enums to be readable when using the ordinal value. Also, isn't the annotation `@Enumerated(EnumType.Ordinal)` the same? Isn't that dependent on the order of the enums?

Comment: You are right, i just wanted to bring this up, actually i don't really see where this bug is coming from, maybe a simple syntax error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like the following, you just had duplicated conditions in `where`:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(c) FROM #{#entityName} c "
    + "WHERE c.feature = :feature "
    + "AND c.rating <= :rating "
    + "AND c.article.ean = c.identification.article.ean "
    + "AND c.date BETWEEN :from AND :to "
    + "AND c.identification.type IN (:types) ")
```

I removed this `c.feature = 'BBN'`

Comment: Isn't the point of named parameters that you can disregard their order in the query itself?

Comment: i just removed 'c.feature = 'BBN'' which sames incorrect

Comment: My bad, I see it now. It should be there, but I missed that it should be OR instead of the last AND feature =...

Comment: could you check the Logging after you updated the query!